# Flashing cursor on boot, nothing happens

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, bootloader

**Note:** I know this is similar to other questions on AskUbuntu, but they are all about Ubuntu 10.* versions as I have seen so far.

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64) and decided to reboot after installing a lot of Python-related packages, and my computer decided to stop booting. It was working perfectly fine before, and not it just shows a flashing underline cursor forever when turned on. I can access the hard drive via the 32-bit live disk that I have, if necessary. I would really prefer not to re-image my computer for the third time, so please help if you can. I have a sneaking suspicion that the 400 some packages that I just installed may have something to do with it.

**Edit:** I can now get to my login screen at least, but the little button that lets you select a desktop environment is missing. Is there something wrong with my desktop environments or something? I'm doing an autoremove right now, hoping that maybe the broken package is being deleted in the mix. (Yes, I went in and tried a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz`, since it was mentioned as depended but not installed, and the system responded with something about not being able to do anything because of me holding broken packages.

Comment: * * * UPDATE: I fixed it! XD When I used synaptic to install 400 packages I overlooked the fact that one of the packages needed to resolve a conflict by uninstalling lightdm, so I messed around in Grub and got it back. So I fixed it that way, and if anyone else finds this problem occuring on their computer, they can use this to fix it...... :| now I need to get my desktop back....

Comment: 99% through autoremove and that random "`unknown media type in type all/all`" is showing up again for some reason... I'm reinstalling Gnome-Flashback right now... maybe that will work?

Comment: OK, I logged in as Guest and was able to see the "Temporary data" window, but not the titlebar, so I think installing compiz and setting it as highest priority may have broken things...

Comment: OK, I'm not getting anywhere, so I'll try running `sudo bash` and then `lightdm` one more time. If I can't get that to work then I'll just have to use this live disk to dump off my files and reimage it.

Comment: I had a similar issue which was resolved by removing the USB flash drive that was inserted. Until I did this, it would not boot. I assume it was trying to boot off it and failing. May help future visitors.